# Square Connect API - image upload - Response 100

Tags: wordpress, curl, square-connect

I am using the following example and keep getting an response from the server of 100. The image does not update in Square at all.

Found from:
[Square Connect API - image upload - Empty Reply From Server code 52 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31349302/square-connect-api-image-upload-empty-reply-from-server-code-52-error)

https://gist.github.com/tdeck/7118c7128a4a2b653d11

(blanked out locationa and item id)
POST to https://connect.squareup.com/v1/XXXXXX/items/XXXXXXX/image with status 100

I am using your example exactly Here are the variables I am sending to it: This is coming from a wordpress install.

```
uploadItemImage( 
'https://connect.squareup.com/v1/XXXXX/items/XXXXX/image', 
'XXXXXXXXXXX', 
'wp-content/uploads/2015/04/imagename.jpg' 
)
```

);

Here is the curl output I get with the jpeg added in Item ID and Token are obscured.  The image getting uploaded is quite a bit larger then 209bytes. But that is all that is getting sent.

```
[url] => https://connect.squareup.com/v1/me/items/ITEMID/image
[content_type] => 
[http_code] => 100
[header_size] => 71
[request_size] => 288
[filetime] => -1
[ssl_verify_result] => 0
[redirect_count] => 0
[total_time] => 61.486827
[namelookup_time] => 0.114398
[connect_time] => 0.225888
[pretransfer_time] => 1.347979
[size_upload] => 209
[size_download] => 0
[speed_download] => 0
[speed_upload] => 3
[download_content_length] => -1
[upload_content_length] => 209
[starttransfer_time] => 1.396955
[redirect_time] => 0
[redirect_url] => 
[primary_ip] => 74.122.189.136
[certinfo] => Array
    (
    )

[primary_port] => 443
[local_ip] => 192.168.1.117
[local_port] => 60968
[request_header] => POST /v1/me/items/ITEMID/image HTTP/1.1
Host: connect.squareup.com
Accept: */*
Authorization: Bearer TOKEN
Content-Length: 209
Expect: 100-continue
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------754042306466c83e
```

Comment: How large is the image you're trying to upload?

Comment: I have tried all differnet sizes. It is roughly 10kb but up to 60kb 150x150 or 750 x 750px

Comment: Working node.js snippet for image upload here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51289166/square-connect-api-image-upload-node-js/51314822#51314822

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a mime-type check was added to the API since I wrote that example code. In order to add the content type header to the image part of the multipart request, you need to change

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ['image_data' => "@$image_file"]);
```

to

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ['image_data' => "@$image_file;type=image/jpeg"]);
```

After trying that, it worked for me. I'll update my gist to reflect this.

Comment: Hi Troy, Thanks for the response, updated the code and still getting the 100 continue issue. I have upated the question with the curl output.

Comment: I've tried a few different things with this code, and have been unable to reproduce the problem you're having. If you try running the PHP on your local machine, do you have the same issue? Maybe it's some weird bug in an old version of PHP on your host?

Comment: I have used it on a couple different machines. PHP version of 5.6 or higher. Very strange issue. Could it be how I am linking to the image? Do you need server absolute path to work? I have been using relative.

Comment: I think your best bet might be to email developers@squareup.com with information about your merchant token, item ID, etc... Then someone might be able to look through the logs and help you.