# Square Connect API - image upload - Node.js

Tags: node.js, multipartform-data, square, node-request

I've spent days trying to successfully upload images with the image_upload endpoint using the Square Connect v1 API. The [API docs are here](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1#post-image)

Currently, I'm getting the following response after making the POST.

```
{"type":"bad_request","message":"Could not create image"}
```

I'm using the node-request library as such:

```
const formData = {
      image_data: {
        value: BASE64IMAGE,
        options: {
          'Content-Disposition': 'form-data',
          filename: 'hat.jpg',
          'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg',
        },
      },
    };
    request.post(
      {
        method: 'POST',
        url: `https://connect.squareup.com/v1/${location}/items/${item_id}/image`,
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`,
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=BOUNDARY',
          Accept: 'application/json',
        },
        formData,
      },
      (err, httpResponse, body) => {
        if (err) {
          return console.error('upload failed:', err);
        }
        console.log('Upload successful!  Server responded with:', body);
      },
```

Has anybody out there been able to use this endpoint successful using node.js?

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to use the official SDK?

Comment: Hmmm.. that's a good point. I suppose I just like to know what is happening under the hood, but in this case, I'm definitely willing to try. https://github.com/square/connect-javascript-sdk

Comment: Actually it turns out the sdk doesn't support the image upload endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting an error is you need to provide binary image data, but you're providing `base64` encoded data. You can see an example of how to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38023426/sending-image-as-binary-via-requirehttp-request-to-a-remote-server#answer-38023739).

Answer (score 0):

After many days of playing around, I finally got it working. Although, in the end, I was not able to make it work without first saving the image to disk, and then posting it to Square. Here is my working snippet:

```
let mimeOptions = {
 'Content-Disposition': 'form-data',
 filename: 'photo.jpg',
 'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg',
};
if (type === 'png') {
 mimeOptions = {
  'Content-Disposition': 'form-data',
  filename: 'photo.png',
  'Content-Type': 'image/png',
 };
}

const options = {
 url: shopifyImage.src,
 dest: `${__dirname}/temp/${uuid()}.${type}`,
};

download
 .image(options)
 .then(({ filename, image }) => {
  const formData = {
    image_data: {
      value: fs.createReadStream(filename),
      options: mimeOptions,
    },
  };
  request.post(
    {
      method: 'POST',
      url: `https://connect.squareup.com/v1/${squareCredentials.location_id}/items/${
        squareProduct.catalog_object.id
      }/image`,
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${squareCredentials.access_token}`,
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=BOUNDARY',
        Accept: 'application/json',
      },
      formData,
    },
    (err, httpResponse, body) => {
      fs.unlink(filename, () => {});
      if (err) {
        return console.error('upload failed:', err);
      }
    },
  );
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.error(err);
});
```